# algorithm to compare a sorted array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have two sorted arrays. I need to find if both are different r not.

These arrays have elements in a **specific range**.

**More that one** element may be different.

Arrays can have different sizes. In this case I should be able to point out the differences

**A rough example:**

Input:

```
array1: 1 2 4 5 8 9 12
array2: 1 4 8 10 12 13 14
```

Here the range is 1-15.

What is the most optimum compare algorithm?

I should be able to point out the differences and similarities too, e.g. 4 is in both and 5 is missing in the second array.

**My solution:**

1. Two pointer to keep track of the index of the array.
2. Point them to the start of the array.
3. Start compare the first two elements.
4. If both are equal--> move to the next one.
   else

   1. Find the largest of the two elements of the array. say array1 has the larger element.
   2. Binary search for the element in the other array.(array2) --> pos of that element in that array say pos
   3. **Discard** the elements of the array till pos.
5. Increment pointers. **discard** that part of array till this pointers. repeat.

This has a complexity of `n log n` (much less than that on average, this is when you have to do a search for every element).

Comment: What is your language ?

Comment: If you want to check whether two arrays contain the same elements and both arrays are sorted, just walk through the arrays. That's the most simple solution and has O(n).

Comment: Why the discarding? Why finding the largest? You could just print out the smallest, increment the pointer of only that array and compare again.

Answer (score 2):

(4.) - instead of binary search do a linear search.

Overall complexity: O(n) - as you visit every item exactly once.

Comment: it's not about finding out if they are different. it's about finding out how similar they are.

Comment: ...and? "finding out how similar they are" is a pretty vague term. what do you want to do?

Comment: It can still be done in linear time, and I believe he means he wants to output a set of numbers in both arrays then a set where these numbers only appear in one of the arrays

Comment: @Don: his algorithm already classifies elements as same (both equal) or different (the rest), so not sure what he's asking for.

Comment: He's asking for something more efficient, and actually your answer is incorrect. As it could end up with O(n^2) complexity in the worst case. as you would be doing a linear search (n) for each of the elements (n)

Comment: @Don: pointers always move forward, so I don't see how you could do more than n work altogether for all the searches.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath based on his algorithm, if you run a linear search instead of a binary search, you could end up searching the other array n times, where n is the size of the longer array, the pointers move forward but you could search the whole array every time it moves forward (if one array had 1-10 and the other 11-20 for the range 1-20) so searching n times with the complexity of the search being n you get n^2. re-read his algorithm. Even if you only search the remaining section of the array that's still n^2

Comment: @Don: nope, pointers don't go backwards. they stay where you finished the search.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Oh the pointers for the search, got it. I still think eliminating the search altogether is the better option, See my post.

Comment: @Don: if you do linear search, as I suggested, then you end up with the algorithm you described. That is, after realising that there's no difference between the regular and the search step. I thought it was obvious, but apparently it wasn't. sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Totally untested (and doesnt work well when there are duplicates):

```
var same = new List<int>();
var inAonly = new List<int>();
var inBonly = new List<int>();

int b = 0;
int a = 0;
//first look at all the elements until one of the lists run out of elements
for(; a < inputa.Count && b < inputb.Count;) {
     //if element is the same, then add to same
     //and the problem with duplicates is found here, if a contains two "1", but b only contains one, then same will report a single "1", but inAonly will also contain a "1"
     if (inputa[a] == inputb[b]){
       same.Add(inputa[a]);
       a++;
       b++;
     }
     //otherwise, we check if a < b, if that is the case, we know that a only exists in a, otherwise it must only exist in b.
     else if (inputa[a] < inputb[b])
     {
        inAonly.Add(inputa[a]);
        a++
     } else         {
        inBonly.Add(inputb[b]);
        b++
     }
}
//add the rest of the elements if one array is longer than the other
for(; a < inputa.Count;a++)
   inAonly.Add(inputa[a]);
for(; b < inputb.Count;b++)
   inBonly.Add(inputb[b]);
```

Comment: correct-ish answer, however lacking explanation, also assumes b will be the longer array

Comment: Yeah, added some comments and fixed the problem with the assumption b is longer

Answer (score 0):

As both array`s are sorted. Best is to use a linear search.

Comment: it's not about finding if they are different.it about finding how similar they are.

Answer (score 0):

If the arrays were blocks of memory - something that you might have allocated with malloc, you can speed up the compares by casting the array to 32 or 64 bit integers. That way you'd be able to compare a number of array elements with a single == test.

Also if you kow the array has a specific number of elements then unrolling the loop to, say, 8 if statements will be faster. It will save the compare and jump at the end of each run through the loop.

Comment: Or you could just, you know, `memcmp` or equivalent standard function. But the OP has said this isn't what he is looking for either way.

Answer (score 0):

@Alvin
Your algorithm seems to be right for me. As you have to point out similarities and differences you will have to do search in case of every difference.

I think that complexity will be better than nlgn, as you dont have to search in the complete array on every difference. This is because you are discarding the elements till pos as well.

Answer (score 0):

If array1 and array2 have the same size then iterate over them and compare them element by element. When first difference is found => the arrays are different. If you reach the end of the arrays it means they are equal. The complexity is O(array's length) in time and O(1) in memory.

If array1 and array2 have different size then allocate another array with size - the range of the elements, and initialize it with zeros ( array3 ). For every element in array1 increment element in array3 like this: array3[array1[i]]++

After that iterate the same way array2, but decrement: array3[array2[i]]--

After that for every element in array3 you have 3 possibilities:

- if array3[i] == 1 //then element i is in array1 but not in array2
- if array3[i] == -1 //then element i is in array2 but not in array1
- if array3[i] ==0 //then element i is in both arrays or in none of them.

Time complexity - O(range), memory complexity - O(range). If the range does not start from 0, then you can make an offset for every index.

Example:

- range: 1-15
- array1: 1 2 4 5 8 9 12
- array2: 1 4 8 10 12 13 14

After step1 array3 will look like this:

```
index: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15

value: 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1  0  0  1  0  0  0
```

After step2 array3 will look like this:

```
index: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15

value: 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 -1  0  0 -1 -1  0
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the correct track with how you approach this, however the search isn't necessary. (see bottom for actual algorithm)

start with 2 pointers pointing to the beginning:

```
        v
array1: 1 2 4 5 8 9 12

        v
array2: 1 4 8 10 12 13 14
```

(just as you have) if the elements are the same add them to you `"In-Both"` set then increment **both** pointers so now we have:

```
          v
array1: 1 2 4 5 8 9 12

          v
array2: 1 4 8 10 12 13 14
```

So now we come across differing elements, instead of searching here we can take advantage of the fact that we know for a fact there can not be a 2 past where the pointer is in `array2` so we add `2` to our `"Only_in_array1"` set. and increment only the **`array1` pointer**. so we end up with:

```
            v
array1: 1 2 4 5 8 9 12

          v
array2: 1 4 8 10 12 13 14
```

We end up with matching so we add 4 to the `"In-Both"` and increment both pointers:

```
              v
array1: 1 2 4 5 8 9 12

            v
array2: 1 4 8 10 12 13 14
```

If you continue this pattern you'll eventually end up with:

```
                     v
array1: 1 2 4 5 8 9 12

                  v
array2: 1 4 8 10 12 13 14
```

and when the first pointer falls off the array you'll know the rest of the elements in the second (longer) array aren't in the first.

***To Generalize the algorithm:***

> - Start with 2 pointers at the start of both arrays (and initialize and datastructures you'll want to hold information: I used 3
>     lists/sets)
> - You can now have one of three cases
>
>   1. **value of p1 is equal to p2**:
>         Add the value to your `in both` array and increment both
>   2. **value of p1 is less than p2**:
>         Add the value of p1 to your `only in array1` array and increment only p1
>   3. **value of p1 is greater than p2**:
>         Add the value of p2 to your `only in array2` array and increment only p2
> - Loop on those conditions until you reach the end of one (or both if it happens that way) of your arrays. Then add any remaining items in
>     the other list to it's respective `only in arrayX` list.

This algorithm only hits each item once so it should be O(**n**). Hope this helps